# Android Camera (photos not showing)

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, imageview

Im developing an Android app and I want my app to take pictures and show them.
My problem is that it makes the picture, stores it on the SD Card but doesnt show it in my app, the ImageView remains blank.
Heres my code:

```
public class OfferCreation2 extends ActionBarActivity {

private Uri imageUri;
private static int TAKE_PICTURE=1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer_creation2);

    Button buttonTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePhoto);
    buttonTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    });

}

private void takePhoto(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture.jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

        ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageProduct);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try{
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(OfferCreation2.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(OfferCreation2.this, "FAIL?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_offer_creation2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used to capture the image and save it to the Image View it will solve your problem let me know if you need more clarity.

```
ImageView ivCapture;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ivCapture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCapture);
            ivCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

              Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              ivCapture.setImageBitmap(bp);
           }
```